# two apps running simultaneously in one activity

Tags: android

How to create an app that opens whatsapp and browser in half half screen. without using split screen built in mode. just using two fragment or two relative layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. An app can not "embed" other apps. You have to use split mode.

Comment: Thanks for answer but then how split screen apps on play store work for even lower android phones?

Comment: Multi window support has been added with Android 7.0. Before, it is not possible.

Comment: ohk great but can you tell me how should I achieve the following

Comment: ohk great but can you tell me how should I achieve the following : use android ip webcam  which is available on play store to send jpg stream to python server and after processing on server python will send results to the app. now all this is easy. but the tricky part is how to put ipwebcam app inside my app at half screen (not implemented ) to show live camera and other half will show  the text results (implemented ). for this reason i wanted to put another app ie ipwebcam as fragment (which you said that it is not possible ) so BRUNO you think is there any alternative apart from splitscreen.

Comment: Try to see if the mentioned app allows to be use by intents...My 2 cents, you have to develop the part dealing with your IP webcam.

Comment: hey bruno what you mean by 'allows to be use by intents'?

Comment: another alternative was i could just start camera preview in my app and ipwebcam will run in background but the issue still is that camera cannot be used by two different apps at same time.

Comment: Please, post another question as your first demand is, I think, resolved